# IBM APIC 2018.1 connect with DataPower 7.5.2.0

Tags: ibm-datapower, apic

We have new IBM APIC 2018.1 Management + Developer Portal  which manage with IBM Cloud Manager.

I try to add DataPower 7.5.2.0 gateway into Cloud Manager and it's return no error; I guess It's cannot connect to 5550 port.

I read this topics http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_sm/2/649/ENUS5725-Z22/index.html&request_locale=en
and there information only about DataPower 7.7.

When I press ADD Gateway I see an error that Datapower alredy exists but after refresh here is no Datapower gateway.
Maybe IBM APIC 2018.1 doesn't supports DataPower 7.5.2.0 
Can you help me to resolve this porblem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIC 2018.1 requires DataPower firmware 7.7+

Comment: Tell me please how can I add Gateway (DP 7.7) into Cloud Manager 2018.1 if I need to use only one DataPower 7.7  server (when I try to enable Gateway Manager Service it requires Gateway Peering* )

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Pankratov
There is a very helpful reply here:
[API Management 2018.1 and DataPower 7.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774156/api-management-2018-1-and-datapower-7-7)

When it comes to configuring DP's APIC Gateway Service, I found it useful having instructions from both APIC and DP:
 APIC, see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_2018/com.ibm.apic.install.doc/tapic_install_datapower_gateway.html

DP, see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/apicgws_configuring.html

Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

Your question statement doesn't quite line up.  If you have APIC Management 2018 there is no add server button only add gateway service.  The APIM server is no longer aware of each member of the gw service.  Adding and removing gw service members is now done on the Datapower and clustering is represented by the gateway peering object.  Also, as previously stated if you want to use 2018 on your datapower then you will have to update the Datapower firmware to 7.7+.  This is a requirement for APIC 2018.

Some key differences in V5 and 2018:

V5 APIM: Create service and add gateway member to the service via the add server button in cmc.  Handles setting up the APIM domain on datapower and installing all necessary artifacts.  All set up is done via SOMA on the 5550 port(usually).

2018 APIM:  Only creates gateway service.  Adding gateway members to a cluster is done via the gateway peering object on Datapower.  Setting up the APIM domain is done by the user prior to registration of the gateway service.  Registration of the service will point to your local address and port defined in the Api Connect Gateway Service object on the datapower or to a load balancer.